# Compass CSS Widget?

Tags: compass-sass

Does anybody know of a widget for Compass (http://compass-style.org/) for Linux? I'd love to have a widget that watches a folder and gives me some sort of alerts for compilation success, errors, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You could just have `compass watch` running in a terminal window. I'm not sure of your setup, but something like [guard-livereload](https://github.com/guard/guard-livereload) maybe more 'widget-y'. I've been using LiveReload for Mac for months and love it.